# How to use localhost in browser instead of localhost:10088?

Tags: webserver, hosts

Installed zend-server CE.

I would like to use this port (10088). 
But anytime I enter localhost I should enter localhost:10088, because localhost doesn't work.

In the hosts file I tried to enter 127.0.0.1 localhost. In this case localhost:10088 works, localhost - doesn't.

If I do 127.0.0.1:10088 localhost both ways don't work.

Answer (score 4):

Web browsers connect to port **80** by default, because it's the default port for `HTTP`. To open a connection on a different port, you need to specify it after the address, as in `http://localhost:10088`.

From the [Zend Server help](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-Community-Edition/ports_and_services.htm#MiniTOCBookMark2):

> Zend Server will be installed on the bundled Apache web server which
>   listens on port 10088 by default. This can be set to another port by
>   editing your Apache configuration file at
>   `/usr/local/zend/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` and changing the value of the
>   directive `Listen`.

So if you want Zend Server on port 80 just make change described above.

Changes in `/etc/hosts` that you described couldn't work - in hosts file you can just map IPs to hostnames.

Another solution will be creating some redirections on firewall using iptables, but for me it will be overkill...